# Use php if to show a form based on users selection from previous page

Tags: php

Am actually new to PHP and am trying to show or hide a form based on what a user selected from a previous page.
In the previous page I have a selection form whereby a user can select from the list of provided items 'Ripple or Bitcoin'. now when the user click on next it shows what the user selected from that page and display another form for address, now if the user selected ripple, then I want to display another from for ripple tag in addition to the address form.

Comment: It's hard for anyone to help you if you don’t provide any code or examples. Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Look into query strings and `$_GET`  if you are unsure where to start with this. https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, Initially I was trying to add the code but i was getting error because I dont know how to post code on Stack Overflow, but I have been able to do it. thanks to you all